# Visibility Issues when comparing two lists

Tags: javascript, react-native

I currently having visibility issues with my list. I am able to make the correct comparison (confirmed with console.log). I need to accomplish this with set, but with the setFavData(mealList), it is not storing anything. If I can get some advice or insight, I would much appreciate it!

Relevant Code:

```
  const [favData, setFavData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    getFilterFavMeal();
  }, []);
   function getFilterFavMeal() {
       allData.forEach((mealList) => {
           currentSelection.forEach((mealList2) => {
               if (mealList["menu_item"]["menu_item_id"] === mealList2.value) {
                        // with push, I have visibility issues
//                       favData.push(mealList);
                      setFavData(mealList);
               }
           });
       });
       setFavData(favData);
   }
```

Edit:

allData component:

```
  Object {
    "menu_item": Object {
      "has_eggs": false,
      "has_fish": false,
      "has_gluten": false,
      "has_milk": false,
      "has_peanuts": false,
      "has_shellfish": false,
      "has_soy": false,
      "has_treenuts": false,
      "has_wheat": false,
      "hash_id": "9ba6364c-fff7-4333-87f0-a20ac32984b7",
      "is_vegan": false,
      "is_vegetarian": false,
      "item_name": "Gluten Free Cookies",
      "menu_item_id": 33,
    },
    "station": "Gluten, Dairy and Nut Free",
    "timing": "11:00:00-14:30:00",
  },
```

currentSelection component:

```
label: Gluten Free Cookies, value: 33
```

Comment: can you paste your allData, I mean how does it look like?

Comment: @MudassarAli updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const favData = allData.filter(a => currentSelection.some(c => c.value === a.menu_item.menu_item_id));
```

Solved my issue!

Answer (score 1):

I guess the last `setFavData(favData);` resets your state. You can try remove it. If it does not work, can you post the full snippet so others can debug ?

Comment: that did not work. I have inputted all the relevant code though, the problem is how I am using setFavData